# Show that group homomorphism reduces the order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $f:G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, need to show

$ord(g)=n \Rightarrow ord(f(g)) \le n $ for all $g \in G$

I suppose one starts from the definition of homomorphism: $f(g \bullet h)=f(g) \ast f(h)$

But where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(g)^n=f(g^n)=f(1)=1$ whence the proposition follows. [One can in fact show that the order of $f(g)$ divides the order of $g$, by a euclidean divison argument.]

Comment: I actually got that too but couldn't see how the proposition follows, because this shows $ord(f(g))=n$ instead of $\le n$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Alex by definition or otherwise, the order of $g$ is the smallest $n$ such that $g^n=1$.